# VB app to web service

Tags: service

I know very little about web service but I assumed it would be the solution I was looking for. Basically I made an application in VB that I want to be ubiquitous for a lack of a better word. I need it to receive requests from multiple users and respond all at once. I was told "technically if you write a webservice you can provide as many results back to users as are connected."

Maybe there is another solution for me that will give me the results I want.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

Lets say I make an application in VB that does math.

I now make a website. My website allows for a person to input 1 + 1 
they click submit and my website then connects to my VB application running on my server
listening for a request. It accepts the request from my website, and then it solves the math problem and returns the answer back to the website "1 + 1 = 2"

That is only an example of the type of thing I need. My problem is that I can't have multiple people visiting my website all connecting to that same application running on my server so somehow I need the application to be where it can be accessed by multiple users. I was told a web service would be the answer but if there is another solution I'd like to know.

If the only solution is a web service, then how can I manage to either convert the VB app to a web service? Can I have to convert the app to asp.net or some other language? Is there an easier option?

Comment: Hi Brandon, please take more time to write your question so that it's easier to read (here it's a big block of text and I'm not really sure what's your problem). You'll get more answers that way.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about what you're actually doing, I might suggest that building an ASP.NET project around your existing VB code might be a good approach. It's going to be awkward to build any kind of "web service" around an existing (presumably GUI) application, so rebuilding your code inside ASP.NET would be the way to go.

Comment: Can I convert VB.NET code to ASP.NET? I don't know much about asp.net

Comment: As far as I know, ASP.NET allows you to write server side code in any .NET language, including VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it the push notification way.

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Windows-Phone-7-Push-Notification-QuickApp--Web-Service-With-Azure-Publishing-Instructions

You can inform users of your application via a push notification